# Git branch suddenly became master

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm keen to understand what happened. We created a git branch, after the work was done we created a PR and it was ok. Then locally I changed the branch to be master and started working again. Then I realized that the PR has all commits "REMOVED" and now master is equal to the branch that was created! We had a setting in BitBucket to forbid any changes to the master branch, I would like to know what and how it happened.

[image]
[image]

Updates based on the comment:

1. The strategy we use is "Squash, fast-forward only"
2. I asked a guy to merge "master" into the branch, but it looks like master was merged into a branch. Is that possible with a setting `Prevent changes without a pull request`?
3. In order to fix that, I created a new branch from master. Reverted all changes, created a PR, merged that PR. Now master looks like it should, but! I open that crooked PR and what I see is `Shchukin, Petr remotely merged the pull request from xreg-3170/Link-foreign-key-transfer-institution-mapping-and-sis-integration-table-by-grantee-tenantId to master` How did I remotely merged that branch?

Comment: 1) Did you merge the PR? 2) What merge strategy did you use? 3) Did you recreate the branch? 4) What is the name of the branch? This looks like a fast forward.

Comment: This could be explained if after renaming your branch to master, you pushed your local `master` branch, and if BitBucket let you do that even though you thought you didn't have permission to push directly to `master`.

Comment: Or, if another PR with a branch based off of yours was completed before the first one.

Comment: Just a small amendment on the chronology I changed the branch to be master (via GitGraph in VS Code as usual) -> Then I realized that master = that branch with REMOVED tags on it -> then I created a new PR to revert master -> after this PR was merged the text of "branch was remotely merged" appeared on the first. Oh and also that branch had "BASE BRANCH" tag on it. Thanks for the clarification, I'm just thinking how to prevent that in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a [fast-forward](https://bitbucket.org/blog/fast-forward-merges-bitbucket-cloud-default-like). It's a merge strategy that Git will pick if the branch is a simple descendant of master. No merge is necessary.

For example, let's say your repo looks like this.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
             \
              E - F - G [branch]
```

When you merge branch into master, no merge is necessary. Git simply moves master to where branch is.

```
$ git merge branch

A - B - C - D - E - F - G [master]
                          [branch]
```

[Bitbucket offers this as a merge strategy](https://bitbucket.org/blog/fast-forward-merges-bitbucket-cloud-default-like). It may be [the default](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-a-merge-strategy-for-a-project/).

I prefer disallowing fast-forwards and always requiring a merge commit. This makes it clear the work was done as a unit, and it provides a place to document the PR and issue # for reference later.

```
$ git merge --no-ff

A - B - C - D --------- M [master]
             \         /
              E - F - G [branch]
```

---

> Then I realized that the PR has all commits "REMOVED"...

I haven't used BitBucket, but here's my guess. Since master and the PR branch are now at the same commit there are no differences. BitBucket is communicating that as the previous differences having been "removed".

BitBucket knowledge base as [How to find all added or removed commits from Pull Request Updates?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-to-find-all-added-or-removed-commits-from-pull-request-updates-1031838165.html) which might be useful to verify what happened.

Comment: I agree with everything in this answer, except that the screenshot shows the commits were removed, so I think something outside of the PR in question had to update `master`, and my guess is either `master` was pushed or another PR was merged that contained the commits also.

Comment: Agree as well, I updated the topic also we have Squash, fast-forward only strategy. I still don't understand why either of us could to that, if we're allowed to change the master via PRs only (there's a setting in Project Settings)

Comment: @PetrSchukin I've never used BitBucket, but it seems to me that since master and the branch are now at the same commit, the PR now has no differences from master. BitBucket is calling that "removed".

Comment: @TTT [See above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75150541/git-branch-suddenly-became-master/75150922?noredirect=1#comment132623478_75150922). What do you think?

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for the explanation. I figured what happened, but still don't understand how. I had a permission under the repo settings to merge into master and it seems it was me who fast forward it. Now, the problem is that I didn't do any of that. Using VS Code in the left bottom corner I chose "master" in order to checkout master branch. Somehow I got the branch merged into master... Time to give up on fancy ui and use cli?

Comment: And one more addition, the branch was created on Mac, I used to have problems with that my windows machine sometimes goes crazy with branches created on mac (if there's difference in upper/lower case) Don't know if it has something to do with it

Comment: @PetrSchukin Without knowing what commands you ran it's hard to say what happened, and using an IDE makes that harder. As for the Mac, it's probably because Windows uses a different newline from everything else. Add an [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) file to your projects to tell editors how to configure themselves to avoid such whitespace issues.